# Array of anonymous objects with coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

How do I create an array of anonymous objects with the least number of characters with coffeescript?

Here's how little I've got it down to (works):

```
cast:
    [ {name: 'Rob Jr.', character: 'Tony Stark'}
      {name: 'Sam Jackson', character: 'Nick Fury'}
      {name: 'Daniel Craig', character: 'James Bond'} ]
```

I was hoping to be able to do this:

```
cast:
    [ name: 'Rob Jr.', character: 'Tony Stark'
      name: 'Sam Jackson', character: 'Nick Fury'
      name: 'Daniel Craig', character: 'James Bond' ]
```

However I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: [stdin]:20:9: unexpected :
```

It gets confused by the first colon it encounters. Is there some coffeescript magic I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can format it like this:

```
cast: [
  name: 'Rob Jr.', character: 'Tony Stark'
, 
  name: 'Sam Jackson', character: 'Nick Fury'
, 
  name: 'Daniel Craig', character: 'James Bond' 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have a long large list I like to use a csv-style array. I think it also adds to readability. Like [this](http://coffeescript.org/#try:rows%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%5B%22a%22%2C%20%22b%22%2C%20%22c%22%5D%0A%20%20%5B%20%201%2C%20%20%202%2C%20%20%203%5D%0A%20%20%5B%20%204%2C%20%20%205%2C%20%20%206%5D%0A%5D%0A%0Aobjects%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%0Acolumns%20%3D%20rows.shift()%0A%0Afor%20r%20in%20rows%0A%20%20o%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20for%20c%2C%20i%20in%20columns%0A%20%20%20%20o%5Bc%5D%20%3D%20r%5Bi%5D%0A%20%20objects.push(o)%0A%0Aalert(JSON.stringify(objects%2C%20null%2C%202))):

```
rows = [
  ["a", "b", "c"]
  [  1,   2,   3]
  [  4,   5,   6]
]

objects = []

columns = rows.shift()

for r in rows
  o = {}
  for c, i in columns
    o[c] = r[i]
  objects.push(o)

alert(JSON.stringify(objects, null, 2))
```

I have a the code to convert it into the array of objects form in a function in my reusable library. I bet there is something similar in underscore.